# Cannot publish application using 'ns publish ios' command because of bad response from Appstoreconnect API

Tags: ios, nativescript

I'm having a problem publishing my latest application built with Nativescript and Angular to Apple's appstoreconnect.

The problem happens after the successful IPA build step, when Nativescript is connecting to appstoreconnect.apple.com APIs to get data. I've provided correct inputs to the command to the best of my knowledge, with valid Apple ID's and everything. I know because I did publish the app a few months ago with successful results back then.

Does anyone know why this might happen? I'm stuck with this, unable to push my app to appstore.

Command used

```
ns publish ios <appleid> <appleidpassword> <provisioningprofile> --appleApplicationSpecificPassword <apppassword> --log trace
```

The script successfully builds the IPA file, but fails afterwards with the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'summaries' of null
at ApplePortalApplicationService.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/apple-portal/apple-portal-application-service.js:27:53)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/apple-portal/apple-portal-application-service.js:5:58)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Relevant source file: [github repo](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/blob/master/lib/services/apple-portal/apple-portal-application-service.ts)

However, the request made from ApplePortalApplicationService is successful, but the response is not containing any data

```
httpRequest: {
  url: 'https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/apps/manageyourapps/summary/v2',
  method: 'GET',
  body: { contentProviderId: <redacted>},
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Cookie: '<redacted>',
    'User-Agent': 'tnsCLI/8.2.3 (Node.js 12.22.7; darwin; x64)',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate'
  }
}
httpRequest: Done. code = 200
```

With response

```
{
    "data": null,
    "messages": {
        "warn": null,
        "error": null,
        "info": null
    },
    "statusCode": "SUCCESS"
}
```